# Nested columns without using flexbox or grid

Tags: html, css

No css expert here. I want to create nested columns. Many sources show that to create columns, do this:

```css
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"></div>
  <div class="col-6"></div>
</div>
```

This creates two columns of equal width.

Now I want to create equal columns within each of the columns again:

```css
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6"></div>
      <div class="col-6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6"></div>
      <div class="col-6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot use flexbox or css grid.

When I implement that, the css makes everything go wonky.

Comment: "I cannot use flexbox or css grid" - Why not? Any good reason for using those is likely to limit possible solutions in other ways.

Comment: The class names you are using seem to come from a website that uses Bootstrap. Are *you* using Bootstrap? If yes, look for a solution in the Bootstrap docs. If no, get aquainted with css-columns, flexbox or grid. But definitely don't use floats for that purpose.

Comment: *`Many sources show that to create columns, do this: (float and clear tricks)`* probably from old sources from 15 to 10 years ago ;) display:table/flex/grid are made for this, not float ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell what exactly do you mean by CSS going wonky? Here's a JS fiddle with your code. I added background color for visualization.

It looks okay to me, so can you check and elaborate how exactly did you want it to look?
https://jsfiddle.net/zdhov31c/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">c1, row-c1</div>
      <div class="col-6">c1, row-c2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">c2, row-c1</div>
      <div class="col-6">c2, row-c2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background:pink;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**I hope this will help you :)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Columns</title>
<style>

.row{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.col-6{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
content{
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6" style="float: left;">
    <p><content>hello world</content></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" style="float: right;">
    <p><content>hello world</content></p>
  </div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.